# Fallo en configuración de failregex en fail2ban

Tags: regex, nginx

Estoy tratando de configurar el `failregex` de Fail2ban para captar peticiones a `/seccion` del sitio.

Lo que busco con esto es limitar la cantidad de peticiones a esta sección del sitio. Y si el límite de peticiones en un tiempo establecido es superado, bloquear la IP mediante `iptables`.

El problema es que he creado el `failregex` para machear las peticiones del access_log y algo debe estar mal. Porque no hace nada.

Adjunto a continuación la línea del `failregex` junto con parte del access_log. Para ver si alguien puede decirme qué está mal.

```
failregex = ^<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST). .*\/seccion\/*
```

Y el access_log:

> 200.43.12.170 - - [14/Mar/2016:08:34:23 -0300] "GET /js/jquery.flexslider-min.js HTTP/1.1" 200 21422 "http://www.dominio.com/seccion/locales_13/te-regalamos-entradas-para-la-convencian-de-camics-y-anima-level-up_a_219112" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/49.0.2623.87 Safari/537.36"

Comment: Lo que está mal es `^` porque lo aplica después del timestamp, y el punto ...`(GET|POST). .*`... debería ser ...`(GET|POST) .*`... Sin embargo, podría coincidir con más de lo que estás buscando. ¿Hay alguna condición extra en el log que puedas agregar para limitarlo? Además,¿`http://www.dominio.com` es siempre el mismo?

Answer (score 1):

Hice un test con la siguiente regex y me funciona con el log que :

```
<HOST> -.*"(GET|POST) .*\/seccion\/*
```

Aquí hice te dejo con la prueba: http://rubular.com/r/FridZ6jstD (fijate que puse dos líneas de log: una con /seccion/ y otra sin esto)

**UPDATE:**
Puedes usar la siguiente herramienta para probar tus regex: http://thefragens.com/2010/11/checking-fail2ban-regex/